# Unity to Gnome help

Tags: unity, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

im noob in linux, and recently i have installed ubuntu 11.10 but i've always work on gnome environment, 
i really want the gnome environment.
Someone knows a reliable method to change **unity to gnome**

Comment: The process of getting a "almost there" gnome experience is already explained [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic). Have a look. Not much you can do since 11.10 will be using gnome3, gnome2 will not be supported anymore.

Answer (score -1):

If you're going for gnome2 then all you need to do is click on your username at login, at the bottom of the screen you'll see Ubuntu in a drop-box. Change it to Ubuntu Classic.

Comment: He is running 11.10, this is not true anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 11.10 no longer includes Gnome 2.  Gnome 3 is included, but it is rather different from Gnome 2.  Although there are ways to install Gnome 2, I doubt you can achieve good system stability with them, given that Unity runs atop Gnome 3, and Gnome 2 is no longer maintained.  You *can* install Xfce, however.  Enter this command in the terminal and then enter your password when prompted.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Xfce is different from Gnome 2 in some ways, but it is closer to Gnome 2 than anything that you can easily install.  Click the gear next to your username when logging in, and select the Xfce option.