# Is there a way to get Gnome 3 Unity (from 11.10) in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, unity, 11.10, gnome

I have Gnome 3 installed in my 11.04 and I was wondering if I can get 11.10's unity in it

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! :) This is a possible duplicate of [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME 3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

Comment: @jrg He wants to install the version of Unity from 11.10, not install GNOME Shell.

Comment: @rooot45 However, in order to do that, he needs to install the GNOME 3 stack - the only way to get that is to install GNOME shell.

Answer (score 1):

Googling around I find this:

"Upgrade

Ubuntu 11.04 users can upgrade Unity by adding ‘ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ppa‘ to the ‘Software Sources‘ dialog, then running Update Manager."

I haven't tested yet, but may works.-

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way is to download the source and install it.

Comment: I have gnome 3 shell. I'm wondering if I can get the unity from 11.10 on to it.