# How can I build GNOME Shell from jhbuild?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell)

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, and wanted to build gnome with `jhbuild` to get the latest and greatest. Unfortunately the setup scripts wants me to install `xulrunner-dev` and `libreadline5-dev` which are both missing from the package repositories. I was wondering if I can just ignore them, or is there some way I can get them?

Comment: Are Universe and Multiverse Enabled in your sources?