# Can't install Gnome-Shell in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

help me please....
I can't install gnome-shell in ubuntu 11.10
i follow this tutor

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-session
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
```

but when I try to run "sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-session" i have some error
this error:

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-icon-theme-full but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-session-fallback but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

please help me.....  T_T

Comment: You don't need to add the PPA for gnome3 in 11.10. It is present in the repositories already.

Comment: All you need to do is "sudo apt-get install gnome-shell" in a terminal

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? I find that if the updates are acting up, that's pretty much always the case.

However, if this causes a problem, then give `sudo apt-get install -f` a go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried this tutorial: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/gnome-shell-ubuntu-11-10-guide/

Normally you don't have to add the ppa. In 11.10 gnome-shell is in the archives.