# Will using the GNOME 3 PPA in 11.10 break Unity?

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome

I like Unity, but want to have newer versions of GNOME software. Will the PPA break Unity in 11.10 like it did in 11.04?

PPA is: https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3

Comment: Can you link to the PPA on launchpad that you're talking about?

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3

Comment: Also, the `gnome-shell` package [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell) has the latest stable release of Gnome Shell (3.2.1). Are you looking to install a preview release?

Comment: I don't see the point of installing this ppa. It looks like nearly all the packages are for natty, and it doesn't even have the latest version of Gnome Shell. Ubuntu 11.10 ships with Gnome 3 by default. if you want to install something more bleeding edge, you can, but I don't think this package is what you want. If you just want to install Gnome Shell, use the package I listed above. It will not break Unity.

Answer (score 3):

The PPA description clearly answers your question:

> This PPA is EXPERIMENTAL and MAY BREAK YOUR SYSTEM. There is no downgrade process.

Answer (score 1):

In 11.10 gnome 3 is in the software center from first. Just search "gnome shell" and it will not break unity.

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

Answer (score 0):

It will not. Natty uses GTK2 under the hood while Gnome shell upgraded it to GTK3. Since both Unity for Oneiric and Gnome shell uses GTK3 and hence Gnome3 nothing will break!

Answer (score 0):

No..Not at all...and it is very easy to install it as well...just type the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

And then while during the login choose Gnome....

for more detail and pics you can visit this link (on my blog):

http://www.computerandyou.net/2011/10/how-to-install-gnome-3-in-ubuntu-11-10/