# something went wrong with gnome3 installation

Tags: gnome

i issued the following commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

and then i found the following change in the system :

[image: screenshot of the installed software list]

but i dont find my desktop looking like [this](http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/).

WHAT has gone wrong ? please help !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your theme has a problem. Found something similar on [superuser.com here.](https://superuser.com/questions/268781/ubuntu-gnome-shell-decorations-theme-broken)

*The answer from the source reads:*

> Try this, it worked for me:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge gnome-accessibility-themes
> sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard
> ```
>
> Then open the Gnome Tweak tool listed above and select Adwaita

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.10 uses Gnome 3 by default, and you don't have to add any PPA to get that desktop. It's in the official repositories. It's called [Gnome Shell](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-shell).

Comment: But the screenshot suggests that the user is on Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal and not Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot

Comment: yes, but I would always recommend upgrading Ubuntu instead of installing Gnome from a PPA.

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps unfortunate that you have installed Gnome-Shell on Natty (11.04) with that particular PPA.

In the PPA description:

> === Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) === This PPA contains packages from GNOME 3.0 and their dependencies. It is considered EXPERIMENTAL and MAY BREAK
>   YOUR SYSTEM. There is no downgrade process.
>
> === 2011/12/30 === There is no further Natty/11.04 support from now on!

The Gnome-3 packages in that PPA have now moved on and are increasingly incompatible with the remaining Natty packages.  Even if you resolve this particular theming issue - you will increasingly encounter newer problems as time goes by and further updates are made.

I hate to say it - and the maintainers make it clear - you will need to reinstall your system :(

1. Backup you `/home` folder to an external hard-drive,
2. install 11.10
3. use [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell) to install gnome-shell
4. copy back your files to your new home folder.