# How to run gnome 3 shell after it is installed

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell)

I installed the scripts to install gnome 3 shell and I cant change from unity to gnome?  Whats the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

If you have properly installed it (`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`) you first have to logout. Next to your name, there is a gearwheel-symbol. Click on it and select Gnome Shell. When you now login, you'll be facing Gnome Shell. This change is being remembered, so if you want to switch back to Unity3d for example, you would have to logout, press the symbol, click on Unity3d and login again.

Comment: There is no Gnome Shell option at login screen, the right label is only "Gnome".