# Can I get Gnome 3.2 working on 10.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell)

Tried a few how-to guides on the web and to no avail. Is there a way to do this and does it work okay without breaking anything?

Craig

Answer (score 0):

No, the changes in your system packages would be just too much.

Gnome 3.2 uses GTK3 packages and those are not available for 10.04.