# Gnome Shell - Can I install alongside Unity

Tags: unity, gnome

Im currently using Ubuntu 11.10 (on Mac on Virtual Box) and thinking of installing Gnome Shell because of its similarity with Mac interface.

If i install Gnome Shell will I need to reinstall printer, webcam drivers, etc.?

Also, will I be able to switch back and forth between Unity & Gnome Shell.

Comment: initially you received downvotes from people probably because your question could have been interpreted as subjective "how does it fair with". http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnome-Shell, Unity etc are just Desktop Shells.

Yes - you can flip between them.  Most shells such as Unity and Gnome-Shell share many of their underlying components.  Thus printing, webcams etc will work whatever shell you use - and no - you dont reinstall these drivers for each desktop shell.

Some useful info below.

---

1. [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-des-and-shells-are-available)
2. [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell)