# User menu in Gnome Shell (Gnome 3.4) - entries missing

Tags: gnome

For example there is no logout button:

[image: Screenshot user menu]

If I log in with the guest session, everything seems to be fine (there is a log out button). I tried to remove my whole user directory and create an empty one, but the problem remains.

I am running Gnome Shell 3.4 using the PPAs ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 and ppa:ricotz/testing as described [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/117026/27088). I disabled all shell extensions and restarted the computer, but the problem remains.

Another difference between my user and the guest user I noticed: when I close the last window on the current workspace, the activitiy overview appears. This annoying beheviour seems to be disabled for the guest user.

I'm thinking to switch to Debian. I try to get 12.04 running with Gnome Shell since 2 days now...

Comment: Why did you use those repositories? You shouldn't need them in 12.04

Comment: @jP_wanN The linked answer says "a lot of the 3.4 packages will be installed by default minus a few that will be kept at 3.2 for stability reasons". Well, yeah, that does not say that it is a good idea to use these packages, but with 3.2 the extensions weren't working well.

Comment: I installed it through the official repositories and it works perfectly. You should always try the stable packages from the official repositorys first. Try removing the ppas with ppa-purge and reinstalling gnome-shell through the official repositories.

Comment: @jP_wanN Ok, I'll try to do that - thanks! Maybe I'll just give it a another try with a fresh installation. Actually I think I was wrong when I though I'd need the new gnome shell version 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reinstall (with the same home directory) without the mentioned repositories solved the problem. I don't know why I thought I'd need newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a new user account and selectively moving your files from the old account in to the new one? If not, try that. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I did not want to mess up my passwd file and get in trouble with different UIDs, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi i used too the ricotz gnome shell ppa, i use synapse launcher to log out session, because the new versions not comming with this option yet. synapse works to logout. i don' t miss log out option in user menu. ( sorry my bad english :P )