# How to install and enable GNOME shell?

Tags: installation, gnome, desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell)

I wanted to install GNOME Shell 3.4 on my Ubuntu system. I tried running a lot of commands I found on a blog, but nothing has worked, and I still have Unity's look and feel. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also I would like that in the first paragraph where I mentioned Unity, I meant the Dash interface. Thank you.

Comment: First [remove all those PPAs you installed](http://askubuntu.com/q/307/24694) to clean your system. Then wait for instructions on how to install the latest GNOME. I've cleaned up your question in the interest of making it more useful to future visitors, best of luck in getting GNOME 3.4 installed.