# Why all gnome extensions showing outdated?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I have installed Gnome 3 on Ubuntu today following this [guide](http://www.filiwiese.com/installing-gnome-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/). All worked well and I have installed the extensions mentioned without problem.

However, after logging out and in, all extensions were gone. Going to the Gnome extensions website, I saw that all my extensions were outdated and that I could install only one other extension.

I'm rather new to Ubuntu and completely new to Gnome. I don't even know how to check my own version (there's no mention of Gnome in System Information) - I reasoned maybe I'm using an outdated version, even though `apt-get` update/upgrade/dist-upgrade does not upgrade anything or solves the problem.

How do I get things back working? I've uninstalled all my extensions, but that didn't do the trick, either.

Update: I tried to install the one extension the gnome website shows as valid, but nothing happens; same when trying to install 'outdated' extensions. I see the popup, choose install, nothing happens.

Comment: To see the installed gnome version post the output of `gnome-shell --version` .

Comment: $ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.5.4

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is a bit dated now, but I thought it worth mentioning that I had a similar problem to Raf, and in summary I think it has been solved by the following:

1. Purge the testing repositories (ricotz and gnome3-team)
2. Purge gnome-shell
3. Purge gnome-shell-common (this was my biggest problem)
4. Reinstall gnome-shell (after apt-get update)

Credit belongs to, and more detailed information can be found at, this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2009222

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed GNOME 3 from above mentioned page repository, you most probably selected the **Quantal repository** or you are using **Ubuntu Quantal** under development release.

As per mentioned gnome-shell version 3.5.4 you are actually using a **newer version yet to be released in stable repository for Ubuntu 12.04 Precise.**

You are most probably using [Ubuntu Quantal quetzal gnome-shell package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/gnome-shell) .

Since currently in active development , no extensions are being ported or developed for **3.5.4 unstable release** .

My guess, wait for stable release ought to be announced as **3.6** in October later this year and consequently in Ubuntu Official stable source.

As per [this page](https://live.gnome.org/ThreePointFive) it states **`GNOME 3.5.4 as unstable release`**

> Remember that 3.5.x is a development release and it should NOT be
>   installed on production machines. It is intended to be used for
>   testing purposes only.

---

To revert it back as per this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/28392/63025)

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

To install Gnome 3.4

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

To remove the Gnome 3 PPA  open  **`software sources`** from Dash or through `update manager`  in `settings` menu  , then go to as image and remove or delete the `gnome 3 ppa` listings manually ( *i don't have it* :P ). Then do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and install gnome shell as above command.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is most likely true, however unintentional. How can I revert to Gnome 3.4.x?

Comment: Apt-get automaticaly selects version 3.5.4. I removed my version, but can't select the stable version. What to do?

Comment: Edited the answer , please comment if this worked or if any encountered errors :)

Comment: Performing the suggested actions yielded a long list of libs that were removed, even as far as Rhythmbox that was removed, but trying to install gnome shell still gives:The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.4.1-0ubuntu2) but 3.5.4+git20120721.r1.dd80f390-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz1 is to be installed

Comment: Thank you for your help, but after the ppa-purge I've lost so much stuff and I'm still unable to use Gnome, I think I'll resolve it by reformatting the harddrive.

Comment: Edited do follow that before formatting , it will be resolved.

Comment: Since you took the time to try once more, I tried once more. But it's no use, even after manualy removing the ppa, I still get the same error message when trying to install Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

My solution (cause I was having the same issue after i upgrade to Gnome 3.6) was the following:

```
cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
mv <extensions you are having issues with> ~/Desktop
```

Then `Alt+F2 then r and then enter` (Note: this will restart your gnome session without you have to restart the computer)

Then you should be able to go into [gnome extensions](http://extensions.gnome.org) and install the new versions. I think there is some issue with properly being able to download and replace other older versions (especially if they were installed through other PPAs.

*Remember* you got to use Firefox also since Chromium is not always that reliable :(