# No gnome shell after install on ubuntu 12.04 inside VMWare workstation

Tags: gnome, vmware

I created a virtual machine for ubuntu 12.04. I then installed GNOME3 from the software center, [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell). However after install I don't get the new gnome shell, in the terminal gnome-shell --version tells me that I'm using the latest version, 3.4.1.

My interface now looks like this: [image: interface]

Does anybody have an idea why I do not get the latest gnome shell?

@Histo yes but why I don't have this interface? [image]

Comment: 3.4.1 is the current version availible in the software repositories. The screenshot you posted looks like gnome shell to me so i'm not sure what your question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is probably with virtual machine. If Gnome3 fails to load, it recovers as Gnome classic (Gnome2) and that's probably what happens for you, first screenshot confirms that.

You can try typing:

```
gnome-shell --replace
```

in terminal to see what exactly happens, it probably wont work or if Gnome3 is forced you may experience some graphics issues. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will kill your windows manager and allow you to take a look at some terminal output.

You may not be able to run Gnome3 in virtualized environment, try Googling, but as far as I know it requires 3D support.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think you are correct that when you say that the problem is most likely in the VM. The command worked;
> gnome-shell --replace
But it is very unstable, a lot of flickering of the screen. And not very responsive.