# How to get Gnome shell 3.6 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell)

simple as install gnome shell 3.6 on Ubuntu 12.04? Some PPA?

Comment: 29 Sept 03:23am +8 GMT - the latest version isn't even available in the GNOME 3 PPA

Comment: This should remain closed and the master answers should be updated (if required). The from-source answer should still apply.