# Safe to install Nautilus 3.6 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, nautilus

I tried installing the new nautilus via commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

But the console warns me not to do that:

```
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 Before upgrading your system to a new Ubuntu release (i.e. from Ubuntu 12.04 to 13.04), you should probably run ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 first.

=== Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) ===
GNOME 3.8 that won't make it into the normal Ubuntu 13.04 repositories. Other parts of GNOME 3.8 are available in the https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging PPA but beware that many of those components have known regressions from their GNOME 3.6 versions.

You need to run 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' to avoid problems. Please read the output before entering 'Y' to make sure important packages won't be removed.

=== Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal) ===
Parts of GNOME 3.6 that didn't make it into the normal Ubuntu 12.10 repositories.

=== Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) ===
Parts of GNOME 3.4 that didn't make it into the normal Ubuntu 12.04 repositories.

=== Bugs ===
On Raring (13.04) please use 'ubuntu-bug' to report bugs against packages in this PPA
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
```

So, is it safe to install Nautilus 3.6 on Ubuntu 12.04? Has anyone tried and did any problems appear?

Comment: It may not be compatible with 12.04 as it is part of the 13.04 distribution. It may be possible see http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome

Comment: I just tried that, and it installs Nautilus 3.4.2

Comment: I would say its stable, safeness well if you follow closely to this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/344370/is-there-any-way-to-install-latest-nautilus-file-manager-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts you will be fine. I have done this many times. Fact, if you install this version and then run the ricotz testing ppa (Aka Gnome shell PPA) for the first time you will be able to have both versions. I'm also flagging this question to a duplicate of that question