# Missing features in Gnome after installing

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, filemanager

I installed GNOME by following the instructions listed in :

[How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome)

Installation went through with no problem but I couldnot get the complete experience of GNOME.

I will show it through the following image:

[image]

This shows that I am still stuck up in a file manager similar to Unity, and features like minimise are missing.

I wish to know how to get GNOME into proper shape.
Will I be able to install apps like GNOME maps, Musics, ect...

Comment: The file manager is called nautilus and both unity and gnome-shell use it by default.

Answer (score 3):

You're problem is that you are using Unity's theme. Gnome uses Adiwaita by default. To change your theme, follow these instructions:

1. Open Terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run the command `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
3. Enter your password, then press <kbd>Y</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> if asked whether you would like to install the software.
4. Open up the Tweak Tool you just installed.
5. Click Theme.
6. Change all the settings to the default ones.

To get the Gnome login screen, perform the following steps.

1. Open Terminal.
2. Run the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`
3. Run the command `sudo service lightdm stop`
4. Run the command `sudo service gdm start`

This will set `gdm` as your default display manager and stop `lightdm`.

Now, you should have the full Gnome-3 experience.

Comment: Why can't he just open system settings and change his theme?

Comment: The theme option is only accessible from the Tweak Tool, which is not installed by default if you only install `gnome` and `gnome-shell`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Dillmo . But still the close button has not changed from the unity style; and whenever I logout, I encounter the KDE style login screen. Why is that? How to change that? Also GNOME extensions are not installing. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Gnome maps and music are part of **Gnome 3.10** wich is not incluided in the latest stable ubuntu release (13.10) and gnome-shell also features 'no minimize' buttons since developers didn's see the need of it(I have no idea if you can re-enable the buttons) an even some applications like files(renamed nautilus) and other gnome core applications no longer have a window bar with close button but have this button bundled in the toolbar as you can see:

[image]

http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/