# How do I install Gnome 3.10 in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: gnome

Is this possible, or do I need to wait for Ubuntu 14.04?

Please Help

Comment: @FlorianDiesch, yes *(even though that question is sort-of  ancient)*, but **user218937**, [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/393254/178596) answer may be the one you need. It seems to have not yet made it to the official repositories, so you have to use the `ppa`. Gnome 3.8 can work better though