# The future of Unity

Tags: unity

I used 10.04 for work for a couple of years and found it to be awesome. Then someone convinced me to upgrade to 12.04 because Unity looked good. After wrestling with it for about 6 months I decided to go back to Mate temporarily until a new desktop interface had been designed.

It looks like the up-coming 14.04 still uses Unity. I'm interested in finding out whether Canonical is continuing to pursue the Unity desktop?

If the strategy is going to persist, then I'm interested in discovering what the best tools are to mitigate it's affects on desktop usability? A few years back there was a tweak tool, but it wasn't very comprehensive. I'm hoping that the scope of customizability has improved over the last couple of years?

Thankyou.

Comment: Ubuntu developers are working on Unity 8, which aims for convergence and working across devices (phones, tablets, laptops, TVs). It's a rewrite of Unity in Qt 5. It's said to land on the desktop in 14.10 and is already the default for phones and tablets. If you don't like Unity, then use another desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure Unity easily with [`ubuntu-tweak`](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/download-ubuntu-tweak-084-now.html) & [`unity-tweak-tool`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/). You can find out about even more desktops and how to install them [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available) if you don't want to use Unity.

You may also want to try other [derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives) of Ubuntu, which can have different desktops from Unity preinstalled - these include:

- [Ubuntu Gnome](http://ubuntugnome.org/screenshots/) - has the [Gnome](http://www.gnome.org/) 3 desktop, on which Unity was based.
- [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) - has the [KDE](http://www.kde.org/) desktop
- [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org) - has the [XFCE](http://www.xfce.org/) desktop
- [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) - has the [LXDE](http://lxde.org/image_galleries/screenshots) desktop
  -

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my work is going to force me to use Unity (which sucks because my current desktop works REALLY well) so I'll just need to see how much 'tweaking' I need to do on it. I'll probably end up getting involved with development into 'tweaking' the living hell out of Unity until it's so much not like Unity that I find it an acceptable desktop to use every day.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use GNOME in Ubuntu 12.04 or later.

There are lots of discussion on this, you may want to try this: [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome)