# Cannot update to GNOME 3.12

Tags: gnome, updates, ppa, 14.04

Ok, I tried to avoid asking this question here, as it's noobish and and always closed/downvoted, but I cannot figure it out myself.

I'm on 14.04 and trying to update GNOME from 3.10 to 3.12. Most blogs and such link to [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3/+index?field.series_filter=quantal). But I cannot figure out how. I added the PPA, I updated the list of repos but still the 3.12 is nowhere to be found.

How can I do it? I ran out of ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PPA you linked to is the main PPA for the GNOME team. The 3.12 packages are not yet available there.

If you are willing to deal with possible issues, you can use their [staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging). Packages there are tested before being moved to the [main PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3).

Similar questions seem to be referred to the following question. This is silly because since the latest GNOME is not in the Ubuntu repos, it does not really answer your question (unless you want to build it from source, in which case you can follow the the second answer).

[How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome)

Comment: Hmm, ok. But gnome.org "announced" the release of 3.12 about a month ago, along with other blogs. [See here](https://www.gnome.org/news/2014/03/gnome-3-12-released/). That thew me off...

Comment: Yes, 3.12 has been released, but it takes some time for it to be available for certain distributions. If you want to always have the latest software versions, look into a rolling release distro like Arch.