# gnome issue on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome

i want to install gnome on my ubuntu 14.04 this is the error it gave me.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
gnome is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (>= 1.3.10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: The error is fixed like @avinash-raj said, but maybe what you are trying to achieve is this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome

Comment: Avinash Raj  i have done that this is the output http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=nvMsBJMw

Answer (score 3):

as the error speaks you should run the command sudo apt-get install -f and you are done it was just due to the broken packages and by typing this command your problem will be solved

Comment: i have done that this is the output pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=nvMsBJMw