# Can I get the GNOME environment in Edubuntu 14.04?

Tags: gnome-classic, edubuntu

I am trying to get a new version of Edubuntu. I just want to check whether I can get the GNOME environment on Edubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know Gnome is coming with standard Edubuntu installation. Before the installation begins the installation wizard is asking to install Gnome and you can select it.

Comment: should we select the option before downloading the iso image or should we do it during installation . i mean is the gnomed edubuntu iso different from normal edubuntu

Comment: i have downloaded the iso image of edubuntu but there is no option to install gnome can you elaborate your answer

Comment: No, it's not different iso but the regular. I have installed edubuntu 14.04 few days ago and there is gnome. I forgot to make printscreen but I found this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhyljrVKhlI). Take a look at 0:20 and you'll see that there is a checkbox for installing Gnome Fallback.
Sorry for the late answer:/

Answer (score 2):

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

It should then install it and most of the other stuff it needs to work.

More instructions can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome).