# How can I update my gnome to gnome 3.18?

Tags: gnome, 15.04

I'm using Gnome 15.04 currently.

Comment: If you upgrade to it and don't like something then you can always use `ppa-purge ppa:gnome3team/gnome3-staging` and `ppa-purge ppa:gnome3team/gnome3`  to revert back to the previous version (install `ppa-purge` with `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`).

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not for 15.04. You need Wily, available since of today, and at least one PPA

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

To get more bleeding edge versions of the components, additionally

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Update the package database and upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

And if you have problems, start the commands below to go back to the version of the official Ubuntu repositories

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Comment: No risk, no fun. Try it. **;)**

Comment: Is this answer complete? Don't you have to `sudo apt-get install gnome-something` ?

Comment: @Wildcard: Nope, you shouldn't need to do anything like that. You are upgrading your current packages, not necessarily installing new ones.

Comment: To be more precise: for 3.18 on Wily, you need both gnome3-team/gnome3 and gnome3-team/gnome3-staging

Comment: I hope gnome 3.18 can also be installed on Ubuntu 15.04, Is there any way? I'm not upgrading to 15.10 because radeon driver not working yet

Comment: @A.B. I'd like to go back to Ubuntu 16.04's gnome 3.18 from 3.20, but it spits out [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/20231709/) and gnome stays on 3.20 after the second `ppa-purge` command and a restart. What's wrong?

Comment: gnome3-staging arrived to the end of life: https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging
Don't use it for Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3):

At this moment, you can install Gnome 3.18 on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 Wily by the PPA `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

Comment: You also need the `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` PPA.

Answer (score 1):

If you want update to Gnome 3.18, you'll need upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10.

On Ubuntu 15.04 you just can update only to Gnome 3.16, the actual version bundled with Ubuntu 15.10.

Follows the step by step valid to update to both versions:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/06/how-to-upgrade-to-gnome-3-16-in-ubuntu-15-04