# There's no status bar in Gnome 3.18

Tags: gnome, 15.10

I have Ubuntu 15.10 and I've installed gnome 3.18 using this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678141/how-can-i-update-my-gnome-to-gnome-3-18) and I don't see the status bar or a tray bar like gnome 3.16 and below.

Is this something made in purpose? or something I haven't installed yet? If so, what should I install?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as per @A.B.'s answer, with the changes to the "Notifications" there have also been changes to the "Message Tray".  If you have Icons in the tray, they'll be visible on the lower left.  I'm not sure how valuable this question is from a technical stand point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gnome3-staging PPA has a nifty description in [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging):

`The packages here have been deemed not ready for general use, they have known bugs and/or regressions, sometimes of a critical nature. Mostly things should run smoothly but be prepared to use ppa-purge, when you encounter issues!`

You should probably run `ppa-purge` against the gnome-staging PPA unless you are prepared to deal with some difficulties.