# How to update GNOME to 3.18 without updating Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, updates, 15.10, ubuntu-gnome, amd-graphics

I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10, and I would like to update GNOME to 3.18. I have tried using the normal terminal commands suggested to update GNOME like

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

However, using an AMD GPU and wanting to continue using the proprietary drivers for now, I would like to stay on Ubuntu 15.10 and not upgrade to 16.04 LTS, but these commands seem to both upgrade GNOME and upgrade Ubuntu to 16.04 LTS. So, is there any way to stay on Ubuntu 15.10 and just upgrade GNOME to 3.18?

Thanks.

Comment: What about running `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: tried running sudo apt-get upgrade after running   

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging  

but the GNOME version stayed the same.

Comment: You have to run `sudo apt-get update` after adding a repository, otherwise you won't see any new packages. If you ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` before `sudo apt-get update`, run it again.

Comment: ran update and then upgrade, GNOME still is at 3.16. Believe that GNOME updates are being held back for some reason due to many gnome packages like gnome-shell and gnome-control-center are shown to be "kept back".

Comment: Well `dist-upgrade` shouldn't upgrade your Ubuntu release. That's `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: tried dist-upgrade again, and Ubuntu did stay 15.10 (even though Details shows it as 16.04, command lsb_release -a showed it as 15.10), with GNOME being at 3.18. However, upon installing fglrx, the system booted to a black screen with a cursor.

Comment: That's very strange. Did Details show 16.04 beforehand?

Comment: Nope. Showed 15.10 in the past before dist-upgrade. After the dist-upgrade, it did show something along the lines of "Base version" as 15.10 in Details.

Comment: Something must have happened. It worked fine here http://askubuntu.com/questions/678141/how-can-i-update-my-gnome-to-gnome-3-18/689091

Comment: What desktop were you using before doing all this?

Comment: If you mean desktop environments, been on GNOME 3.16.